# Understanding why binomial expansions for negative integers produce infinite series

Tags: binomial-theorem

I am a mature student self-studying a UK Math A-Level. I have been studying math on and off in my spare time for the past 6 years, so I have some grounding in the subject but it's all a bit piecemeal and disjointed. Hoping doing this A-Level will pull it all together more. I have a decent grasp of most areas up to differential calculus, but there are gaps and some areas are still fuzzy.

I am working through a revision textbook and am currently stuck on binomial expansions for negative integers. I feel like I have a good grasp of binomial expansions for positive integer powers - the binomial theorem for positive integer powers makes intuitive sense to me in terms of combinatorics. But I just can't seem to get an intuitive understanding for why the expansion of a binomial raised to a negative power should be an infinite series.

For example, one example question in my textbook says "find the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^{-2}$, up to and including the term in $x^3$. The $x^3$ term is specified because otherwise the expansion could go on forever".

I must be missing something somewhere. As I understand the exponent rules, $x^{-n} = \frac 1{x^n}$. Therefore I can't see why the answer to the above question wouldn't simply be: $$\frac 1{1+2x+x^2}$$

I have scoured the internet for somewhere to provide an intuitive explanation for why a binomial raised to a negative power should have an infinite expansion, but everything I have come across so far simply states something like "for powers that are not a positive integer, the binomial expansion is an infinite series", without explaining why. Can anyone please help me make sense of this, or point to a resource that provides an intuitive proof/ explanation?

Comment: It’s a generalization of the sum of a geometric series!

Answer (score 2):

The *expansion* has the implied meaning of "as a polynomial in $x$". It is true that

$$(1+x)^{-2}=\frac1{1+2x+x^2}$$ but this does not have the desired shape.

Now a function like $(1+x)^{-2}$ has a vertical asymptote at $x=-1$, and this cannot be modelled by a polynomial, which keeps finite values. To obtain this effect, the polynomial must be of infinite degree, so to say (it is in fact an *entire series*), which gives it the possibility to *diverge to infinity*.

---

Without being aware of the generalized binomial formula, you could solve by the method of indeterminate coefficients. Let the entire series

$$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+\cdots$$ and let us establish

$$(1+2x+x^2)\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k=1.$$

By expanding the product and regrouping the terms of equal degree, the LHS becomes

$$a_0+(2a_0+a_1)x+(a_0+2a_1+a_2)x^2+(a_1+2a_2+a_3)x^3+(a_2+2a_3+a_4)x^4+\cdots$$

and if we set

$$a_0=1,a_1=-2,a_2=3,a_3=-4,a_4=5,\cdots$$ by cancelling all coefficients but the first, we get an "identity" with the RHS. So

$$(1+x)^{-2}=1-2x+3x^2-4x^3+5x^4+\cdots$$ holds when the series converges.

---

Note that this formula is unable to represent the given function "past" the asymptote (when $|x|\ge1$), and this is the rule with entire series.

In green, the true function, in blue the fourth degree approximation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick and detailed response! I'm afraid I'm still confused. I'm going to have to do some more groundwork to understand this I think, but I'm not exactly sure where to turn to start. 

What do you mean by "it does not have the desired shape?" If I try plotting the LHS and RHS of the first equation in your answer on Desmos, the shape is identical.